# Mapping WSDL field names to database values

Tags: java, spring, wsdl

I am currently working on a web service application (WSDL/SOAP). 
Certain tables in our application database are populated via a back-end external process which the web service application does not govern. The xsd field names used when designing the wsdl were created to be expressive so as it is easier for the calling client to integrate with web service.

Now i have to map the xsd field names with the values in one of the external table as mentioned above. I can't do a direct mapping or use reflection as the names of wsdl xsd fields don't match with the table values. For e.g. 
in the wsdl i have a field called "driverAge" whereas the corresponding match table value is "drAge". Here the driverAge is the actual age of the vehicle driver whereas the drAge is a weight associated with the age of the driver. I have to associate the two for some computations.

I want to avoid doing this matching programatically and was looking at a simple approach to do this more by convention or some sort of flexible mapping. May be using Spring Hibernate, since I am already creaing the WSDL classes using wsimport utility.

Can anyone suggest a good design to acheive the mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Directly persist a SOAP message to database is not possible unless you have something like [WSO2 Data Service Server](http://wso2.com/products/data-services-server/) where you can expose database operations as services. But here since you are using spring you can marshal the incoming xml message to a java object using jaxb and then you can persist that java object using hibernate.